# How to add multiple table data content into a function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fairly new to Javascript and am trying to process a page on my website whereby HTML markup is being displayed with what each bit of syntax represents.

I have generated some JS that will take the first element and output it as i want, but what i am trying to do is to do this for every table data element in my table.

For some strange reason getElementsByClassName does not appear as viable syntax in sublime 2.

What i would like to know is how to send all my table data syntax to my function and return it all for output?

```
<div class="container clearfix content">



        <table class="table">


        <tr>
            <td>&lt!DOCTYPE&gt</td>
            <td>Defines the document type</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b></td>
            <td>included Bold text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><aside></aside></td>
            <td>Defines content aside from the page content</td>
        </tr>

        </table> <!-- end of table -->


<div class="jsContent">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var html = document.getElementsByClassName('table'[0].getElementsByTagName('td');
            html.innerHTML = html.innerHTML
            .replace('<', '&lt;')
            .replace('</', '&lt;/')
            .replace('>', '&gt;');
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/2r0yr7hj/1/

and code:

```
 var html = document.getElementsByClassName('table')[0];

tds=html.getElementsByTagName('td');


for(i=0;i<tds.length;i++) {


           tds[i].innerHTML=tds[i].innerHTML.replace('<', '&lt;')
            .replace('</', '&lt;/')
            .replace('>', '&gt;');
}
```

Comment: Ok this has kind of worked except it has displayed all the td tags not the content inside the td. Essentially the desired output is to display <b></b> or <aside></aside> as i'm writing them now. Its being created as a reference guide for HTML syntax if that helps.

Comment: Excellent! thank you for the quick response and understanding. This worked perfectly and i cant thank you enough for your help. Do you mind if i use this for my website? i know its content was not created by me.

Comment: Many thanks. Its a personal and educational website. Thanks again